# Asp.net mvc getvalue viewbag into ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ik have this actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink("some name", "Profile", "Profile", null, new { id = "home-link" })
```

I need to pass a viewbag value inplace off "some name"

Tried a couple of things

```
@Html.ActionLink(ViewBag.displayname, "Profile", "Profile", null, new { id = "home-link" })
@Html.ActionLink(@ViewBag.displayname, "Profile", "Profile", null, new { id = "home-link" })


@{
  var displayname = ViewBag.displayname;
}
@Html.ActionLink(displayname, "Profile", "Profile", null, new { id = "home-link" })
```

None of those seems to work, couldn't find anything so is this even possible?
Thanks

**Added sceenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Try casting your displayName to something.

```
 @Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.displayname, "Profile", "Profile", null, new { id = "home-link" })
```

Comment: Hey Alex, should it? Because my visual studio gives error. I added a screenshot. Tried to show the viewbag but it is setten to a other view. I need to set the value globally, but still then i will get this error tho!:O

Comment: ah, yes. The error you're getting is probably because extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. try casting displayname to something. I'll update my answer